# Magento “Place Order” button redirection to custom Page before Order Succes Page

Tags: magento2, checkout, module, payment-gateway, magentomodule

Basically I want to display custom module page after "Checkout Page" and Before "Order Success Page".

I created the module manually and want to add a page between checkout page and order success page. On that page I have to collect some data from the users (data about the products that he/she selected), after place order button.

After collecting the data from the users, I have to redirect to the Order Success Page.

Any Solution would be much appreciated!

TIA!

Comment: You want this after place Order or before place order?

Comment: Hello @DhirenVasoya After place order and before order success page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open your_company/your_module/etc/frontend/ create a file here event.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
    <event name="checkout_onepage_controller_success_action">
        <observer name="companyname_order_success" instance="CompanyName\ModuleName\Observer\Orderplaceafter" />
    </event>
</config>
```

Then create an Observer folder in your module and place a file Orderplaceafter.php

```
<?php

namespace CompanyName\ModuleName\Observer;

use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;
use Psr\Log\LoggerInterface;

class Orderplaceafter implements ObserverInterface
{
    protected $_responseFactory;
    protected $_url;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\App\ResponseFactory $responseFactory,
        \Magento\Framework\UrlInterface $url
    ) {
        $this->_responseFactory = $responseFactory;
        $this->_url = $url;
    }
    
    public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
    {       
        $event = $observer->getEvent();
        $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
        $_checkoutSession = $objectManager->create('\Magento\Checkout\Model\Session');
        $_quoteFactory = $objectManager->create('\Magento\Quote\Model\QuoteFactory');
        
        $order = $_checkoutSession->getLastRealOrder();
        $quote = $_quoteFactory->create()->loadByIdWithoutStore($order->getQuoteId());
        if ($quote->getId()) {
            $quote->setIsActive(1)->setReservedOrderId(null)->save();
            $_checkoutSession->replaceQuote($quote);
            $url = $this->_url->getUrl('prescription/index');
            $this->_responseFactory->create()->setRedirect($url)->sendResponse();
            die();
        }
    }
}
```

Then run commands:

php bin/magento setup:upgrade
php bin/magento setup:di:compile
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f
php bin/magento cache:flush